# get current domain in a template called from service grails

Tags: email, grails, service, path

I use the grails mail plugin to send mail, I have to send an email from the service and from this i use the grails mail plugin: http://grails.org/plugin/mail

So I have this code:

```
    mailService.sendMail {
        async true
        to 'hello@world.fr'
        from 'world@hello.fr'
        subject subj
        body (view:'/mail/_mailTemplate')
    }
```

So at this point everything's fine , my method send email.

In my mail template i have the image pippo.png that i have to show, and I do it in this way.

> `<img src="${resource(dir: 'images/mailImage', file: 'pippo.png',absolute:true)}">`

In the generated html the link that i get as a result for that image is :

```
http://localhost/images/mailImage/pippo.png
```

with this link is obvious that the mail client will never find the image.

but when i render the same template from a controller i get:

```
http://www.mycorrectdomain/images/mailImage/pippo.png
```

so how can I get the current domain even when i render my template from the service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the grails documentation of the `resource` tag, it says:

> absolute (optional) - If true will prefix the link target address with the value of the grails.serverURL property from Config.groovy, or localhost if there is no setting in Config.groovy and not running in production.

So, I'm guessing the reason you are seeing localhost is because you haven't configured your URL in `Config.groovy`, or, you are not running in production model.

To change the default URL, in `Config.groovy`:

```
grails.serverURL = "http://www.thecorrectwebsite.com"
```

To run in production mode: `grails production run-app` should do the trick.